# Magento2 ui component multiselect selected options on edit

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, multiselect

I'm trying to show the selected options in a multiselect in a custom admin module form.
The data for the multi select field is saved in the database.

What i have as field:

```
<field name="position_options">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="options" xsi:type="object">{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Form\Source\OptionsMultiselect</item>
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
               <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Positions</item>
               <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </field>
```

If i add:

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="string">0,1,2</item>
```

Between  it will hightlight fields with corresponding id's.

But how do i get the data from the database in there? Or do i need to do it in another way?

Thanks in advance!

---

```
<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\DataProvider</argument>



class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var ResourceModel\Data\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection    = $pageCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->meta           = $this->prepareMeta($this->meta);
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepares Meta
     *
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $page) {
            $this->loadedData[$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('module_messages');
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $page = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $page->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('module_messages');
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

Didn't change it in here.
Added

```
 protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);

    $select
        ->joinLeft(
            [
                'rel' => $this->getTable('shirtsbedrukken_overprinttable_data_options_rel'),
            ],
            'shirtsbedrukken_overprinttable_data.sod_id = rel.sod_id',
            ['rel.soo_id']
        )
        ->joinLeft(
            [
                'soo' => $this->getTable('shirtsbedrukken_overprinttable_options'),
            ],
            'rel.soo_id = soo.soo_id',
            ['soo_id']
        );
    return $select;
}
```

Inside \Model\ResourceModel

Was is in the wrong place?

Answer (score 3):

This may be not needed now, but for someone else might;

You need to add below function inside

> ResourceModel/[YourModelName]/Collection.php.

Ex: in this case it's

> vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Page/Collection.php.

```
/**
     * Perform operations after collection load
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        $entityMetadata = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata(PageInterface::class);
        $this->performAfterLoad('cms_page_store', $entityMetadata->getLinkField());
        $this->_previewFlag = false;

        return parent::_afterLoad();
    }
```

Then you need to add the `performAfterLoad` function either in the same Collection.php or in its AbstractCollection class.

You can find the function for this example in following file `vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractCollection.php`

Pls change those functions according to your tables.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. you can use this when you want to display data of two tables in a single form.

Answer (score 1):

When use multi-select Use the data source to add option to select

```
<field name="position_options">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Questions\OptionSource</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         .....
        </item>
</argument>
</field>
```

Ex:

```
<field name="customer_group_ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer Groups</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">catalog_rule</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customer_group_ids</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\CustomerGroupsOptionsProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

PHP Class

```
 class OptionSource implements OptionSourceInterface
    {
       /**
         * Return array of options as value-label pairs
         *
         * @return array Format: array(array("value" => "<value>", "label"=> "<label>"), ...)
         */
        public function toOptionArray()
        {
            /**
             * @var $questionCollection \Namespace\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Questions\Collection
             */

            $questionCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
            $options = [];
            foreach ($questionCollection as $question) {
                $options[] = [
                    'label' => $question->getTitle(),
                    'value' => $question->getId()
                ];
            }
            return $options;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My collectionfactory->create doesn't return my data.
if i do $this->collectionfactory->create()->getCollection()->getData(), i can set my values.
But still they are not selected after save.

Comment: i'm looking for how to do multi select, do you have the answer that you want now? 
please help :)
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238037/magento-2-2-5-explain-about-how-the-multi-select-available-sort-by-get-data

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code below:

```
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">attribute</item>
```

the `attribute` is your attribute name that your saved in database.

Comment: Did not work unfortunately.
I got it as a second table. With a relation table. In my resource model collection i join the tables with _getLoadSelect()
If i dump the query and load it in mysql i get what i want. But i cannot set the options for the multiselect.
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">soo.soo_id</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">soo_id</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">soo.option_name</item>

Comment: Show me your DataProvider @Johan

Comment: Added my code as above :)
I can see what getData returns, i don't see my option name in there..